# vb.net pass parameter to an existing crystal report and export

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have an existing crystal report that accepts one parameter.  I want to use VB.Net or C# to open the report, pass a parameter and then export it as a PDF.

Also, this needs to be a console application that simply be launched.  This does not need to be on a web site.  No UI needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code from most recent attempt:

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
Imports CrystalDecisions.shared
Imports CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports CrystalDecisions.Web
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Module Module1
Sub main()
    Dim myReport As New ReportDocument
    Dim crystalreportviewer As New CrystalReportViewer
    Dim param1Fileds As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterFields
    Dim param1Field As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterField
    Dim param1Range As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterDiscreteValue
    Dim CRYRpt1 As New CrystalReportViewer

    Dim myParams = New ParameterFields()
    Dim myParam = New ParameterField()
    Dim myDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()

    myParam.ParameterFieldName = "@SerialNumber"
    myDiscreteValue.Value = "DA1714625"
    myParam.CurrentValues.Add(myDiscreteValue)

    myParams.Add(myParam)

    Dim cryRpt As ReportDocument

    cryRpt = New ReportDocument()

    cryRpt.Load("c:\users\cjniva\6850.rpt")


    Dim CrExportOptions As ExportOptions
    Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New DiskFileDestinationOptions()
    Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
    CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "C:\\Data\\Data1\\DemoDates.pdf"

    CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
    CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
    CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
    CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions
    cryRpt.Export()

End Sub
```

**Latest Version:**

```
Sub main()

    'Private Sub RunReport()
    Dim report As New ReportDocument
    report.Load("c:\users\cjniva\desktop\6850.rpt")
    report.SetDatabaseLogon("dba", "pw")
    report.SetParameterValue("SerialNumber", "DA3EEXQTO")
    'report.ReadRecords()
    Dim exportFilename As String
    exportFilename = "test.pdf"
    ExportCrystalReport(report, ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, exportFilename)
End Sub

Private Sub ExportCrystalReport(ByRef report As ReportDocument, ByVal exportType As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType, ByVal exportFilename As String)
    Dim expFilename As String = Path.Combine("c:\users\cjniva\desktop\", exportFilename)
    Dim diskOpts As CrystalDecisions.Shared.DiskFileDestinationOptions = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions.CreateDiskFileDestinationOptions()
    diskOpts.DiskFileName = expFilename
    Dim exportOpts As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions = New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions()
    exportOpts.ExportFormatType = exportType
    exportOpts.ExportDestinationOptions = diskOpts
    exportOpts.ExportDestinationType = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
    report.Export(exportOpts)

End Sub
```

Comment: Great, do you have any code? Have you downloaded the dlls needed for CR? This is all completely doable.

Comment: Please see original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple layout including the export part.

```
Private Sub RunReport()
  report.Load(filename)
  report.SetDatabaseLogon(?,?,?,?)
  report.SetParameterValue("nameOfParam", paramValueOrVariable)
  report.ReadRecords()
  Dim exportFilename As String = {some path output name.pdf}
  ExportCrystalReport(report, ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, exportFilename)
  report.close()
  report.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub ExportCrystalReport(ByRef report As ReportDocument, exportType As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType, exportFilename As String)
  Dim expFilename As String = Path.Combine({someDirectory}, exportFilename)
  Dim diskOpts As CrystalDecisions.Shared.DiskFileDestinationOptions = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions.CreateDiskFileDestinationOptions()
  diskOpts.DiskFileName = expFilename
  Dim exportOpts As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions = New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions()
  exportOpts.ExportDestinationOptions = diskOpts
  exportOpts.ExportFormatType = exportType
  exportOpts.ExportDestinationType = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
  report.Export(exportOpts)
End Sub
```

Comment: How should "report" be declared?  As crystal or just a report object?

Comment: Also, dirTiburon is not declared.  What should it be?

Comment: That was a directory I use. Just use a directory on your machine where this will output the files.

Comment: Saying "Error in File C:\Users\cjniva\AppData\Local\Temp\6850 {33CAEAC0-BC60-40E4-904E-ED32B7C334AE}.rpt: Operation not yet implemented."  Not sure why.  I am not using that directory.  My file name is 6850.rpt and the exportfilename is test.pdf

Comment: It uses a temp copy of the CR report for processing. You really should include a directory with the file name when exporting.

Comment: Added my latest version under my original.  Getting the same error.

Comment: you added your directory twice. please debug your work and you would have seen this.

Comment: Apologies.  I wish I was a better programmer.  Where is it added twice?  I change the exportfilename to just the file name and I still get the same error as above.

Comment: You have the full c: path that is sent to the export sub, where you add part of the c: path to it again.

Comment: That error states the file is using something that is not implemented in that system environment. Poss a Font?

Comment: You can also get that error if a function has an error - i.e. Divide-by-zero. Please check your CR file for errors.

Comment: Which line has "the full c: path that is sent to the export sub, where you add part of the c: path to it again"?

Comment: If, using Crystal, I can export the report without error, could I then rule out a font or divide by zero issue?

Comment: I created a new crystal report with just two fields and I get the same error.

Comment: I checked the local temp folder and I am seeing numerous rpt files.  Seems the code is creating them, like test {02D72F3D-E0F1-47AF-A83D-AFC9FB231CAA}.rpt, but doesn't take the next step.

Comment: I don't why it's not working for you. I use this for automated runs every day.

Comment: Don't forget to `Close` and `Dispose` the report object. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: My apologies.  I checked the fonts and found that Times New Roman, Arial and Wingdings were the problem.  Once changed or removed the code works perfectly.  Now I just have to figure out why those fonts are a problem.  Thank you so much.

Comment: ok, be sure to check this as the answer and upvote as needed. Glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with Crystal fonts.  Once I changed all fields to Arial everything worked.